# The Distinct symbols

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols, amssymb

How do I write the symbol x cross in LaTeX. I want the x with a line across the centre point of X. I searched the internet but couldn't get it.

[image]

This is a picture of the symbol

Comment: Do you want an asterisk `*`? In math mode you can also use `\ast` (the same). Or do you want `\times`?

Comment: No. I need  a horizontal line crossing on x

Comment: *horizontal line*? What length? Like minus sign? Longer?

Comment: like minus sign

Comment: From the image you post, (which should be an edit to your question), are you looking for `\mathfrak X`, from the `amssymb` package?

Comment: @Andrew Swann - Thank you ....I am looking for that symbol \mathfrak X

Comment: An image is better than thousand words.

Answer (score 6):

## Interpretation: dash on x

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dashonx}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@dashonx{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@dashonx}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1x$}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1-$}%
  \sbox4{$\m@th#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \dimen@=\wd0 %
  \ifdim\wd2>\dimen@
    \dimen@=\wd2 %
  \fi
  \rlap{%
    \raise\dimexpr.5\ht0-\ht4\relax
    \hbox to \dimen@{\hss\copy2\hss}%
  }%
  \hbox to \dimen@{\hss\copy0\hss}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \dashonx B^{A \dashonx B^{A \dashonx B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result dash on x]

## Interpretation:  ∋ + ∈

The symbols `\ni` and `\in` are combined, the space between reduced and a minus is added in the middle as bridge over the remaining space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\niin}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@niin{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@niin}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1{\ni}\!{\in}$}%
  \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss$#1-$\hss}}%
  \copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \niin B^{A \niin B^{A \niin B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \niin]

## Interpretation: U+2AD8 Superset beside and joined by dash with subset: ⫘

The symbol is available in the OpenType fonts XITS Math and Asana Math and are accessible via package `unicode-math` with LuaTeX or XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll<{$A \supdsub B$}@{}}
    XITS Math & \setmathfont{xits-math.otf} \\
    Asana Math & \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result U+2AD8]

### Version without XeTeX/LuaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\supdsub}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@supdsub{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@supdsub}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1{\supset}\!{\subset}$}%
  \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss$#1-$\hss}}%
  \copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \supdsub B^{A \supdsub B^{A \supdsub B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \supdsub]

## Interpretation: `\times` with horizontal line.

The following example uses `\times` and the minus sign to construct the symbol. The symbol is defined as binary symbol which respects the math style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\timesminus}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@timesminus{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@timesminus}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\times$}%
  \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss$#1-$\hss}}%
  \copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \timesminus B^{A \timesminus B^{A \timesminus B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: form is not like this. my x will be of the form when we writing c in opposite sides a line coming on the centre of that x

Comment: i have reason to believe this might be in the `xits` fonts, perhaps with the name `\dashontimes` or `\xdash`.  it was requested by the stix project, but not accepted by unicode, for lack of compelling documentation.  (i will try again if someone can provide a link to a published example showing it in context, preferably with a clear indication of its meaning.)

Comment: @Anu Can you make a hand drawing and add a scan/photo to the question?

Comment: @Anu Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh6bP.png

Comment: yes the same thing

Answer (score 4):

as suggested by andrew swann in a comment, and confirmed by the op,
what is wanted is `\mathfrak{X}`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\distinct}{%
  \supset
  \mathrel{\mkern-8mu}%
  \mathrel{-}%
  \mathrel{\mkern-8mu}%
  \subset
}

\begin{document}

\[
A \distinct B                        
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The symbol drawn with TikZ:

- Size depends on the current math style.
- Line width depends on the current math style.
- The height is taken from symbol `\subset`.
- The width is taken from the plus symbol.
- The side bearing is guessed from the plus symbol.
- The symbol is defined as binary symbol (`\mathbin`).

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\supdsub}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@supdsub{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@supdsub}[2]{%
  % line width setting adapting to math style
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\mkern.75mu$}
  \edef\@LineWidth{\the\wd0}%
  % height is taken from \subset
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
  % width and side bearing is taken from plus symbol
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1+$}%
  % math axis
  \sbox4{$\m@th#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \edef\@MathAxis{\the\ht4}%
  % height
  \edef\@HalfHeight{\the\dimexpr\ht0-\ht4-\@LineWidth/2}%
  % width
  \edef\@NettoWidth{\the\dimexpr2\ht2-2\ht4-\@LineWidth}%
  % side bearing is guessed from plus symbol
  \edef\@SideBearing{\the\dimexpr.5\wd2-\ht2+\ht4\relax}%
  \kern\@SideBearing
  \tikz[
    line cap=round,
    baseline=0pt,
    yshift=\@MathAxis,
    line width=\@LineWidth,
  ]\draw
    (0, 0) -- ++(\@NettoWidth, 0)
    %
    (0, \@HalfHeight)
    to[out=0, in=90]
    (\@NettoWidth/2, 0)
    to[out=-90, in=0]
    (0, -\@HalfHeight)
    %
    (\@NettoWidth, \@HalfHeight)
    to[out=180, in=90]
    (\@NettoWidth/2, 0)
    to[out=-90, in=180]
    (\@NettoWidth, -\@HalfHeight)
  ;%
  \kern\@SideBearing
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \supdsub B^{A \supdsub B^{A \supdsub B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for could perhaps be a simple calligraphic, script style `X`, such as `$\mathscr{X}$`, from the `mathrsfs` package:

[image]